# How do i use DirectoryInfo and FileInfo to get all files and add the sorted files to a List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to sort the file make from them List to use them later in a method:

```
dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(radarImagesDirectory);
var ordered = dirinfo.EnumerateFiles("*.gif")
         .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime);
FileInfo newest = ordered.FirstOrDefault();
FileInfo oldest = ordered.LastOrDefault();
```

I want to use the sorted files in this method:

```
private List<Bitmap> ConvertTo24(List<string> ListinputFileName)
        {
            Bitmap bmpIn = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < ListinputFileName.Count; i++)
            {
                bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(ListinputFileName[i]);
            }
            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            ConvertedBitmaps.Add(converted);
            return ConvertedBitmaps;
        }
```

Comment: uhm added sorted to WHICH list? (only 1 list is shown in the code: the "ordered")

Comment: Updated my question with the method i want to use the sorted files in.

Comment: you should include the List<string> testfiles in your question as currently ppl have to guess where the mentioned list is as it is nowhere to be seen that it exists, what its type is and how it is named

Comment: You method `ConvertTo24`, will only ever return the last file in your list because you discard all the others in your for loop.

Comment: The ending } of the forloop seems to be misplaced and should be below the ConvertedBitmaps.Add line.   Also is ConvertedBitmaps a global variable? as it is not declared inside the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility to get the list of giffiles and add them to the testfiles (ordering has to be done afterwards) would be this:

```
List<String> giffiles = Directory.GetFiles(radarImagesDirectory, "*.gif")
                                     .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                     .ToList();

testfiles.AddRange(giffiles);
testfiles = testfiles.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

The first line gets all giffiles into a list, the 2nd line adds the list to the preexisting list and the 3rd line orders the list.