# How can i build string variable of the next file should be created from the known last file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the last file:

```
last_file = fi[fi.Length -1].FullName;
```

In this case the last_file contain the directory and the file name:

C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\radar_temp_directory\radar010286.gif

Now i want to create what should be the next file:

```
string nextfile = 
File.Copy(combinedTemp, nextfile);
```

combinedTemp is allways the file name untitled.gif
I want to copy this file to C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\radar_temp_directory\

As radar010287.gif

Comment: Do you mean when `radar000001.gif` exists, you want the next file to be `radar000002.gif`?

Comment: Yes. If the last file is radar345678.gif the next one should be radar345679.gif and i forgot to mention that all the files are built with radar + 6 digits extention gif. radar000001.gif the next one should be radar000002.gif then radar000003.gif and so on.

Comment: CodeCaster not if radar000001.gif exist but any last file it can be radar000001.gif if there is one file in the directory but if there already 10000 files so the next one will be radar10001.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `fi` contains all files named `radarNNNNNN.gif` where N is 0-9 and the list is ordered, you have a few steps to do:

```
// Obtain the file with the highest number, but only the filename, not the path
string lastFile = fi[fi.Length - 1].Name;

// Take the number part of the filename
string lastFileNumber = lastFile.Substring(5, 6);

// Parse it as int
int lastNumber = int.Parse(lastFileNumber);

// Increase it by one
lastNumber++;

// Build a new filename
string newFileName = string.Format("radar{0:D6}.gif", lastNumber);

// And make it a full path again by prepending the directory name
newFileName = Path.Combine(radarImagesDirectory, newFileName);
```

Of course you'll have to include some error handling and include code to make this work when no files are present in the directory.

Comment: CodeCaster i'm getting exception on this line: int lastNumber = int.Parse(lastFileNumber); TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: @Daniel my bad, that was a classic off-by-one error. You can spot it by inspecting the variables.

Comment: CodeCaster i found the problem. If it's like this then the Substring should be: string lastFileNumber = lastFile.Substring(82, 6); why 82 ? since here you did string lastFile = fi[fi.Length - 1].FullName; and UllName including the directory. If i change it only to Name it will be like you did. (5,6) . Anyway it's working now. Thank you.

Comment: Problem is lastFile is a full directory path, you need to do something like = lastFile.Substring(lastFile.Length - 10, 6);

Comment: @WhoIsRich no, he needed `FileInfo.Name` instead of `FileInfo.FullName`. :)

Comment: True, but that makes the assumption the .Name property is available, there is no mention of what method is providing the file list.

Comment: @WhoIsRich according to OP's [question history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215010/how-do-i-use-directoryinfo-and-fileinfo-to-get-all-files-and-add-the-sorted-file) there is. ;)

Comment: Ahaa, will remember to stalk OPs profile next time for clues :)